# Listbox not showing

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

So this is probably an easy one, but I have just started learning the subtle art of C#, so forgive me if I come across as a little 'green'.

I've been experimenting with boxes. ListBoxes as of late, to be precise. In my class I have the following:

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();

lb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
lb.Name = "ListBox1";
lb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(245, 200);
lb.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
lb.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;  

lb.Items.Add("Element One");
lb.Items.Add("Element Two");
lb.Items.Add("Element Two");

lb.Show();
```

Now, I've been working under the assumption that ListBox would somehow work as MessageBoxes do.

I have a:

```
var confirmResult = MessageBox.Show("Question asking about " + variable + "?", "TitleHere", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
```

...and I thought the ListBox would work much the same?

Problem is, it does not.

The MessageBox pops up in all its glory, but the ListBox is nowhere to be seen.

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so `Form` is the way to go they say.

I tried:

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();

lb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
lb.Name = "ListBox1";
lb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(245, 200);
lb.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
lb.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;  

lb.Items.Add("Element One");
lb.Items.Add("Element Two");
lb.Items.Add("Element Two");

Form f = new Form();
f.Controls.Add(lb);
```

Buuut this still isn't showing my pretty box.

Please advise.

Comment: By the way, you could also use the designer. If you want to hide  it initially: `lb.Visible = false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written on Microsoft msdn, the [message box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Displays a message box that can contain text, buttons, and symbols
>   that inform and instruct the user.

and the [ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.listbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Represents a Windows control to display a list of items.

So you don't need a container (like Form) to display a messageBox, but you need one for Controls, like ListBox.

**UPDATE:**

You should probably also add something like:

```
form.ShowDialog();
```

In addition to ListBox microsoft's page you should also check out one about [Form class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). They have neat examples if you scroll to the bottom of the page.

Comment: That did it mate, +1 and a nice big accept to your answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the listbox to a container on your form (e.g. a panel or the form itself).

e.g.

```
MyForm.Controls.Add(lb)
```

or

```
panel1.Controls.Add(lb)
```

You don't need to do

```
lb.Show();
```

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks! +1! Could you read my update, and maybe show me what my new error is? Sucks having to leave a new question without a solution.

Comment: @ViRALiC: I strongly recommend designing forms in the form designer. Creating and displaying forms in code is fine, but placing/sizing the controls in the form (e.g. Listboxes) is best done in the designer. Simply add a Windows form and Visual Studio will set up the designer for you. Things are a lot easier after that.